# Compiling Python 2.7.10 Error

Tags: python, compiling, posix, source, unixware

I want to add Python 2.7 to my Unix.
I downloaded the sources to the VirtualBox on which the Unix is installed and run

```
./configure --prefix=/usr       \
            --enable-shared     \
            --with-system-expat \
```

without problems.

However, when I try to run `make,` it fails on:

```
cc –Kpthread –Wl,-Bexport –o python Modules/python.o libpython2.7.a -lsocket –lnsl –lpthread –ldl –lm 

Undefined                       first referenced
symbol                              in file
_PyInt_FromDev                      libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o)     
UX:ld: ERROR: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to python
*** Error code 1 (bu21)
UX:make: ERROR: fatal error.
```

I tried to find a solution searching on Google, without much success.

**Can you suggest directions towards a solution?**

Environment:

- OS Unixware 7.1.4
- Python 2.7.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make` is successful when `#endif` is moved from line 526 of `Modules/posixmodule.c` to line 513.